# Android Select row by Id in Sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to get a specific row by id in android sqlite and have written the following code, but it does not return any records. I have written a `getAllRecords()` method which returns all records from database.

Can anyone explain mistake I am making?

```
public Bank getBankById(int bankId)
    {

        Cursor cursor=null;
        Bank bnk = null;
        cursor =  this.db.rawQuery("select * from " + BanksTable.NAME + " where " + BanksTable.COL_ID + "=" + bankId  , null);
         if (cursor != null)
            {
             if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                {
             int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(BanksTable.COL_ID));
             String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BanksTable.COL_NAME));
             String url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BanksTable.COL_IMAGE_URL));
             byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(BanksTable.COL_IMAGE));
             bnk=new Bank();
             bnk.setId(id);
             bnk.setImageURL(url);
             bnk.setName(name);
             bnk.setImageByteArray(image);
                }
             cursor.close();
            }
        return bnk;

    }
```

Comment: do you get any exceptions in your logcat?

Comment: where is BanksTable.COL_ID and table definition ?

Comment: db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + BanksTable.NAME +" ( "
    +BanksTable.COL_ID + " integer PRIMARY KEY, "+
    BanksTable.COL_NAME + " varchar, " +
    BanksTable.COL_IMAGE_URL + " varchar," +
     BanksTable.COL_IMAGE + " blob);");

Comment: no i dont receive any exception here....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ended up this problem by changing parameter to name.
Its weird but I still don't know why it was not working.

I was getting bank id like 0,1,2,3,4 maybe it is not allowed in SQLite or internally affecting it but still I am not sure.

```
cursor =  this.db.rawQuery("select * from " + BanksTable.NAME + " where " + BanksTable.COL_NAME + "='" + bankName + "'" , null);
```

Comment: or use trim() method to insert/getting records.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach to get custem object from sqlite db

```
    fun getTaskById(itemId: Int): ModelTask {
    val food= ModelTask()

    val database = readableDatabase
    val kolonlar = arrayOf(DBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_T_ID,
            DBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_T_TITLE,
            DBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_T_DESC,
            DBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_T_TIME,
            DBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_T_PRIORITY,
            DBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_T_DATE,
            DBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_T_DONE)
    val whereClause =  DBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_T_ID + " = ? "
    val whereArgs = arrayOf(itemId.toString())
    val cursor = database.query( DBContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME_TASK, kolonlar, whereClause, whereArgs,
            null, null,  DBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_T_ID + " DESC")

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        food.id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_T_ID))
        food.title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_T_TITLE))
        food.description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_T_DESC))
        food.time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_T_TIME))
        food.priority = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_T_PRIORITY))
        food.date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_T_DATE))
        food.done = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_T_DONE))
     }
    database.close()
    cursor.close()
    return foodList
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding "autoincrement" property to id, while creating the table

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + BanksTable.NAME +" ( " +BanksTable.COL_ID + " 
integer PRIMARY KEY **autoincrement**, "+ BanksTable.COL_NAME + " varchar, " + 
BanksTable.COL_IMAGE_URL + " varchar," + BanksTable.COL_IMAGE + " blob);");
```