# Unable to insert a row in SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table called `app_catagory`. The problem is, when I try to insert a row into the table, I got this exception:

> FATAL EXCEPTION : main java.lang.NullPointerException

The LogCat shows this line as the offending code:

```
db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null, initialValues);
```

How can I fix it?

**Code**

```
static final String DATABASE_APP_CAT= "create table app_catagory(cat_id interprimary key autoincrement, " +
    "name text not null," +
    "date_created date , " +
    "img_name text);"; 

//Insert into catagory table 
public static void insertContact_app_cat()
{
    String[] name={"DOCTOR","PHARMACY","PATHLAB","BLOODBANK"};

    for(int i=1;i<=4;i++){
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_CAT_NAME, name[i]);
        initialValues1.put(KEY_CAT_DATE, "05-05-2014");
        initialValues2.put(KEY_CAT_IMG,"null");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null, initialValues);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, post a complete error log message.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION : main
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I don't think this is a complete error log. :) Anyway try to remove FOR statement for now and check if the error persist. Obviously you need to change name[i] with a string like "test".

Comment: I'm quite surprised that the error is not about `IndexOutOfBoundsException` since the `for-loop` got off-by-1 error.

Comment: i have used for loop and the name[i] for inserting just key_cat_name. It worked in that case.. the problem is while i am trying to insert values in several columns

Comment: here is an example (the question)  Anuty G  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817144/android-select-row-by-id-in-sqlite

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you are getting the db when I do an insert I call this piece of code before doing my ContentValues add stuff.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

Then after the insert I would close the database.

```
db.close();
```